# PHP multiple forms

Tags: php, forms

So the issue I'm running into is I have a project with nested forms to select options and for some reason I cant get it to get beyond the first form. If you run this and select the first button it correctly displays the second button, but after that it just returns to the beginning.

How do I do this correctly? I've tried various methods such as isset, using functions, wiping the $_POST variable, etc and to no avail. Would Google or Stackoverflow this but I'm not quite sure what this problem is called.

This is all being done within a single php file because I don't want to have to deal with leaving the page, and this started out as a simple assignment that I've greatly expanded to fit my needs. Also I know nothing of Javascript and have no interest in using it.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

echo <<< HERE
<form method = "post">
<input type = "submit" name = 'button' value = 'Do thing 1'>
<br>
</form>
HERE;
$button = $_POST['button'];
if ($button == 'Do thing 1'){
echo <<< HERE
<br>
<form method = "post">
<input type = "submit" name = 'button2' value = 'Do another thing'>
</form>
HERE;
$button2 = $_POST['button2'];
if ($button2 == 'Do another thing'){
    echo 'doing another thing';
}

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem #1, nested forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would solve this kind of issue is by sending all the fields and naming the buttons:

```
<form>
<input name="input_1">
<input name="input_2">
<button type="submit" name="button" value="button">Button</button>
<input name="input_n">
<button type="submit" name="button" value="button2">Button2</button>
</form>
```

Then once submitted:

```
if($_POST['button'] == 'button') { 
    /* sanitize input 1*/
    /* sanitize input 2*/
    /* do something */ 
}
if($_POST['button'] == 'button2') { 
    /* sanitize what you need */
    /* sanitize input n*/
    /* do something */ 
}
```

Comment: Hm, I could consolidate some of my forms like that, would definitely make things smoother, but do you know why this happens? Thats really the part that bugs me, it just doesn't make sense, and prevents me from nesting a lot of my functions. For example I want to be able to have a single menu do the following "User chooses to modify database> options (add, delete, etc) > from those choices various forms pop up with what to modify, etc"

Comment: @Sillycollegestudent Your code doesn't work because nested forms are invalid. You can't put a form inside another form.

Comment: What is happening is that you are nesting forms, which is a big NO NO. At the end the program does not know which inputs are for which form.

Comment: well darn, would this still count as nested forms if I had them call functions, IE form1 submit leads to function A and inside function A is another form that leads to function B or function C based on choice and so forth?

Comment: I don't exactly know, but I would say yes, it would be considered nested forms.